# wxpython wxgrid attributes

Tags: grid, attributes, wxpython, attr

I'm having trouble highlighting alternative rows in a grid. Having created the grid and filled it with data, highlighting alternative rows works as expected. But when new data is loaded, I delete all rows, then add new rows as required, and this time grid highlighting raises the exception unhandled TypeError. This has me stumped- any suggestions?
The code below produces the same error (click the button twice):-

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib
app = wx.App()

def highlightrows(event):
   for row in range(0, myGrid.GetNumberRows(), 2):
      if row < myGrid.GetNumberRows():
         myGrid.SetRowAttr(row, attr)
   myGrid.ForceRefresh()
   myGrid.Refresh()

frame = wx.Frame(None, title="Highlight woes")
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
myGrid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
myGrid.CreateGrid(12, 8)
sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
sizer.Add(myGrid, 1, wx.EXPAND)
panel.SetSizer(sizer)

btn = wx.Button(panel,  -1, 'Highlight rows')
sizer.Add(btn)
btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, highlightrows)

attr = wx.grid.GridCellAttr()
attr.SetBackgroundColour('#eeeeee')

frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your `GridCellAttr` instance has gone out of scope and been deleted by the second time you press the button. I'm surprised it worked the first time, to be honest. When I click the button twice, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: in method 'Grid_SetRowAttr', expected argument 3 of type 'wxGridCellAttr *'
```

Digging a bit deeper, if you look at the 3rd argument, you will see that it is the following:

```
<wx.grid.GridCellAttr; proxy of wxPython wrapper for DELETED GridCellAttr object! (The C++ object no longer exists.) >
```

Anyway, here's one simple approach that worked every time for me:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="A Simple Grid")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.myGrid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
        self.myGrid.CreateGrid(12, 8)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.myGrid, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Highlight rows')
        sizer.Add(btn)
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.highlightrows)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def highlightrows(self, event):
        """"""
        attr = wx.grid.GridCellAttr()
        attr.SetBackgroundColour('#eeeeee')
        for row in range(0, self.myGrid.GetNumberRows(), 2):
            if row < self.myGrid.GetNumberRows():
                self.myGrid.SetRowAttr(row, attr)
        self.myGrid.ForceRefresh()
        self.myGrid.Refresh()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: So, (and please excuse my lack of the correct terms) attr should be used more in the manner of a local variable than (as I was attempting) a global variable.

Comment: I tried this in my application, but get another error when I remove rows from the (highlighted) grid. It's late here in Tasmania, but I'll take a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: This is just one example. Technically you could put the `attr` into the `__init__` if you renamed it to `'self.attr`.

Comment: I tried running the code that Mike posted (above), but it gives the same error on the second button press. I am now wondering if I should destroy the grid completely then rebuild it from scratch when the data changes.

Comment: This worked on Xubuntu 14.04 with wxPython 2.8.12.1. You could destroy it, but that seems excessive and I know other people who don't need to do that.There's a virtual grid that people use all the time for database stuff. Alternatively, you might use ObjectListView. I've used that with databases a lot and it works great!

Comment: Interesting. It fails on my Mageia5 installation (Python 2.7.9, wx.version 3.0.1.1), but works OK on my Mageia3 installation (Python 2.7.6 wx.version 2.8.12.1).  I would mention this on the wxpython forum, if there was one...

Comment: There's a Google group that you can post to - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wxpython-users

Comment: Thankyou Mike, I'll do that. I also found one at [link]https://forums.wxwidgets.org/index.php[/link]. I find wxpython very difficult to find help for...

Comment: The wxPython community is very helpful. That Google group is excellent. They also have an IRC channel at #wxpython

Answer (score 0):

Weird - similar issue with code that worked fine in wxPython 2.8. Upon upgrading to 3.0 I had to Clone() the attribute for each row otherwise I would get the type error above:

```
TypeError: in method 'Grid_SetRowAttr', expected argument 3 of type 'wxGridCellAttr *'
```

Thanks to Jim and Lawrie for the suggestion. Could this be a bug? Here's my code:

```
def initialPaint(self):
    wx.lib.colourdb.updateColourDB()
    self.oddLineColour = wx.NamedColour('GAINSBORO')
    oddlineattr = wx.grid.GridCellAttr()
    oddlineattr.SetBackgroundColour(self.oddLineColour)

    for (j, header) in enumerate(self.columnList):
        self.SetColLabelValue(j, header)
        for (i, bond) in enumerate(self.bondList):
            if bond in self.bdm.df.index:
                if i % 2:
                    self.SetRowAttr(i,oddlineattr.Clone())#NOT NEEDED IN 2.8
```

Answer (score -1):

A bit late but, try this. I had the same problem...

```
myGrid.SetRowAttr(row, attr.Clone())
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. It works for the example code above, but not in my project code. I'll have to look into that.